# CodeIgniter Routing Not Working in Sub Directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have setup a CodeIgniter site but only the default routing seems to be working.

I have had to set it up as a sub dir of an overall site - so http://localhost/subdir is the default url - this seems to work with the basic out of the box routing.

I have added a Users controller with the following methods - login, logout, register so I was expecting http://localhost/subdir/users/login would work but I get :

The requested URL /subdir/users/login was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2k PHP/5.4.44 Server at apps.mediaforce.co.uk Port 80

My routes file is very basic so I tried adding a new route to it for the users controller but it made no difference.

```
$route['users/login'] = 'subdir/users/login';
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include `subdir` in your route.

Hence update your `$route['users/login']` to route to following:

```
$route['users/login'] = 'users/login';
```

---

**Edit 1:**

in your root create a `.htaccess` file if it doesnot exist and save the following content in it to remove `index.php` from your URL:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Hi - I have changed it to :

$route['users/login'] = 'users/login';

but still get the same message :

The requested URL /subdir/users/login was not found on this server.

Comment: check the controller name and method name again.

Comment: I can get /subdir/index.php/users/login to work but /subdir/users/login does not. Looking at PHP info mod_rewrite is loaded.

Comment: Then it's the problem with your `.htaccess`

Comment: @chilluk check my updated answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed - turned out that our .htaccess file was being completely ignored - sorted that out in the config and now all is well based on the above rewrite rules.